# Does SSD fail immediately?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

There are cases when HDD may fail immediately. This usually happens due to failure of electronic components (like HDD controller) but not due to breakage of disk itself. Usually instead of complete breakage you get bad blocks on your HDD. In this case, some data is lost but most survives.

What about SSD? They usually have multiple chips of flash memory. What if one chip fails? Will SSD continue to work? How much data will be lost?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when an SSD fails, it is completely gone and little in the way of recovery capability. I think some recovery agencies have the capability but it is very expensive.

High quality and commercial SSDs have extra cells to provide the ability to put data in always good cells of the module.

Quality of SSDs has improved so that the good ones are guaranteed for as long as 5 years.  The total number of writes that are allowed before a drive expires from writes is way in excess of constantly high usage over the 5 year period.

Main point:  use high quality SSD drives.